# I need to use the output of if statement outside the if statement but i have an error

Tags: java

hello i have this code and i want to use the variable "mid" out of the if statement but i cant because it's private it could be used only inside the smaller if statement.

```
    int mid;
    int high = Math.max(Math.max(R1, G1), B1);
    int low = Math.min(Math.min(R1, G1), B1);
    if (high == R1) {
        if (low == G1)
            mid = B1;
        else
            mid = G1;
        System.out.println("mid is: " + mid);
    } else if (high == G1) {
        if (low == R1)
            mid = B1;
        else
            mid = R1;
        System.out.println("mid is: " + mid);
    } else if (high == B1) {
        if (low == G1)
            mid = R1;
        else
            mid = G1;
        System.out.println("mid is: " + mid);
    }
    System.out.println("High is: " + high);
    System.out.println("low is: " + low);
    int v = high;
    int s;
    int h;
    if (v == 0) {
        s = 0;
        h = 0;
    } else {
        s = (high - low) / high;
        if (s == 0) {
            h = 0;
        } else {
            double alpha;
            alpha = 60 * (mid - low) / (high - low);
        /* problem here in mid variable above, it's not taking the output from if statements */
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you simplify your code to show minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1):

Just initialize `mid`. Now issue fixed.

```
 int mid=0
```

Your current code

```
 int mid; // not initialize 
 int high = Math.max(Math.max(R1,G1),B1);
 // rest of the code
```

When you come to last `else` your `mid` is not initialized.

Comment: Thank you so much Ruchira , but actually when i initialize the value it takes the output 0 all the time and it don't take the output from the if statement.

Comment: @amnehobaid then initialize `mid` inside the `else` with corresponding value before use it in `else`.

Comment: If the mid is still 0 when you return the value, it's probably because either R1/G1/B1 is 0, or because you are not entering any of the if statements

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera I think the problem just solved when i initialized the mid at the beginning of the code.. thanks again <3

Answer (score 0):

It's not taking it because its entering NOONE of your if conditions... 
If you don't initialise it and the code inside your messy if conditions is not executed OF COURSE it will not have a value different from 0.