# the output of an operation is always zero what ever the input was

Tags: java

I have this code and the output of variable `s` is always zero:

```
double v = high; double s; double h;
if (v == 0) {
    s = 0;
    h = 0;
    System.out.println("v and s and h is zeroo" + v + s + h);
} else {
    s = (high - low) / high;
    System.out.println("s is equal to" + s);
    System.out.println("high is equal to" + high);
    System.out.println("low is equal to" + low);
    if (s == 0) {
        h = 0;
        System.out.println("high and low are equals" + high + "==" + low);
    } else {
        double alpha;
        alpha = 60 * (mid - low) / (high - low);
        System.out.println("alpha is : " + alpha);

    }
}
```

example of the output:

```
s is equal to0.0
high is equal to139
low is equal to30
high and low are equals139==30
```

Comment: Where are low and high defined?

Comment: are high and low integers?

Comment: they are defined at the beginning of my code

        int high = Math.max(Math.max(R1,G1),B1);
        int low = Math.min(Math.min(R1,G1),B1);
and their values are printed in the output(no problem in their values.) could it be because i'm defining them as int ?

Comment: and where is 'mid' declared?

Comment: Where is `mid` initialized?

Comment: i think the problem was that i defined low and high as integers . Thanks so MUCH

Comment: dude, yo're asking the same twice:
[same]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26057568/i-need-to-use-the-output-of-if-statement-outside-the-if-statement-but-i-have-an).

Comment: i'm new in this site and actually i don't understand it very much.

Answer (score 4):

Since  both `high` and `low` are of type `int`, the division in the line `s = (high-low)/high` uses integer division, and since `high - low` will always be less than `high` (unless low is a negative number), the result will always be zero.

To fix this, cast one of them to double:

```
s = (high-low)/(double)high;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just defining a variable as `double` type doesn't mean the operation itself will be of double precision.Your high and  low are 139 and 30 which are integers and **Integer/Integer** is an **Integer** which you are then expanding it to a double(ie. 0.0)

Just cast either high or low as double and you will get the result as double precision

```
 s=   (high-low)/(double)high;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since high and low are ints, the result of

```
(high-low)/high
```

is calculated as an int value.

Try:

```
1.0*(high-low)/high
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a rounding problem. Declare high and low as doubles if you want to perform correct division with them.